# Failure Injection:Try to write into protected RAM area

Tags: c, pointers, ram

I'm working on an home project to learn more about embedded systems. So I'm also not professional with C language :)

Lets say I have a struct:

```
static st_struct myStruct;
```

The struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct  
{
   int a;
   long xy;
} st_struct
```

To keep the code simple here, the struct is defined and  only valid within a protected RAM area, in the address space from  0x04001000 - 0x04003000.
This protected area prevents other tasks to write into it, they can only read.

If some task/function is trying to modify or write into this area, the CPU will reset.

The variable myStruct is located within  address 0x04001f15.

I would like to provoke this behavior of trying to write into the "not allowed", exactly to the myStruct variable. What would be the best way to implement such kind of failure injection in this example? Can you give an example how to do this with pointer arithmetic?

Comment: If you say that the struct is indeed placed in the area, why don't you simply do `myStruct.a = 0; myStruct.xy = 0;` ?

Comment: It's unclear to me how you are arranging to have the structure located in the protected area, but it is plausible that you have done so.  With that being the case, assigning values to its members, as @AjayBrahmakshatriya suggests, should cause attempts to write to that area.  So as to avoid any possibility that those writes are deferred or optimized out, you should declare the structure `volatile`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the struct is declared and only valid within the RAM protected area. So outside only reading from struct is possible but not writing. Writing will cause a reset of CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want the code for the *other* application so produce the faulty behavior.

In the other process/program do this

```
typedef struct  
{
   int a;
   long xy;
} st_struct;
st_struct *ms = (st_struct*) 0x04001f15;
ms->a = 0;
ms->xy = 0;
```

This way the other application will try to access the same struct and will fault.